# How to build a website on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, hosting

I've just started diving into **Node.js** after several years of **PHP** programming and I would like to build a **Node.js** app for my next project, but I have no clue how to do it.

Are there any resources for a Node.js jumpstart?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should think of Node.js as some kind of Apache + PHP, meaning that you can program your website and your webserver with Node.

Node has some important differences with your basic PHP, it's evented, asynchronous, non-blocking. You have to learn how to deal with callbacks, don't block the event loop and other things.

What you should do is try to learn the basic stuff with Node at the beginning, here are some great resources: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info (my favorite has been [nodetuts.com](http://nodetuts.com/) and the excellent book by it's author, Hands on Node).

After you've learned the basics, you can find [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) really useful as a web framework and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) if your app is focused on real-time.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're searching for a node.js jump start to build some meaningful web page with node. Take a look at [express](http://expressjs.com/), which is a node web framework. They offer a nice but short tutorial (under guide).

Answer (score 5):

You need to run Node.js on a web server. Basically, you need a VPS or Dedicated Server over which you have full control. [PHP runs through the standard web server, Apache. Node.js *is* the webserver.]

Or you find a [Node.js host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app) that'll do it for you.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but is it possible to run node.js server on my university computer?

Comment: The link for the Node JS host is no longer working, kindly update your answer

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is essentially your webserver that would replace Apache so the only hosting that you would find to run Nodejs is a dedicated server or a cloud instance in which you would have to install and run nodejs on. The machine that you run node.js on needs to have a domain name pointed to it or the only way you can access the server is by its IP address which is this case your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use something like Knockout.js (http://knockoutjs.com/), and have the page make JSONP calls to the Node.js server. It's really easy to use Node to send JSON to the client, since it's JavaScript on the server. Using a framework on the client makes it really easy to create a dynamic page based on that JSON data.

The disadvantage is there is no graceful degredation for older browsers. The advantage is a potentially blazing fast website with great AJAX built-in right from the start.

Here is some sample code for using Node to generate a JSONP response:

```
function writeJsonpResponse(res, jsonpcallback, obj) {
    var serialized = JSON.stringify(obj);

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    res.write(jsonpcallback + '(' + serialized + ');');
    res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the README.
Setup environment.
take a look at package.json (or npm init to create one)
install dependencies (npm install / axios, nodemon, express, mysql, react, babel)
add scripts to start server & webpack if needed
Get acquainted with file structure.
separation of concerns - public/dist, server, db, client
think about the flow of data
Ensure basic HTML structure.
check that bundle.js file / everything it needs is loaded in
need a div id to render react with (like app or root)
Spin up Express server.
Start server and webpack is separate terminals.
check for console.log that server is listening!
Write routes (get and post requests) on your server.
check that get & post requests are working w/ Postman!
Create mySQL database (db/index.js).
Design & import schema (how to structure data tables).
make sure you’re in the db folder when importing yr schema girl! 
Connect db to server.
check for console.log that connection is successful!
Write insert/retrieve db query functions.
don’t forget to module.exports those queries to the server!
will call query functions in routes/get & post requests in server
Set up basic React structure.
index.js’s only task is to render your app component to the div id app
need a stateful App component to render all other components
remember to import & export default everything!
Design the rest of your components, decide whether or not they will be functional (stateless) or class components (stateful).
draw it out!
what props (data & functions) do you need to pass down?
Write those components.
Work through one data flow that executes through all the pieces. Get your input handler to send the client side POST request (using axios) to the server route, which will execute your API call (if there is one) and then insert that data to the database. 
remember to handle your errors!
Handle events / conditional rendering.
1. user event gives input (onChange e.target.value) 
2. write a handleChange f(x) to update state to that new input
3. input is submitted (onClick)
3. write a handleSubmit f(x) that takes in the updated state and makes an axios POST request w/ that { input } to the appropriate server route
remember to bind method functions appropriately!
Call query functions in routes/get & post requests.
Check that data from the client is being stored in the database.
describe those tables my friend!
Do an AJAX get request (use axios or fetch) on client side to api endpoint.
Store the incoming data in setState
May want to do a GET request in componentDidMount to always render appropriate info for client
Yay! You successfully set up your server, database, and client, passed data between them, potentially manipulated the data, stored that data, and displayed the appropriate data to the client!
Tackle those user stories!